# Auto Login To a Site

Tags: java, authentication

I'm trying to create some kind of script to login and click on a certain link on a site. I've included the login script from the main site and was wondering if any of you could tell me how to enter my username and password into this code that way when I load this site, it automatically loads. Or if anyone could make a script that would work to click a link as well that would be amazing.

```
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="Skin-CustomLoginTable">
<tr>
    <td class="Skin-CustomLoginLeftSide">

    </td>


        <td class="Skin-CustomLoginRightSide">
        <div class="Skin-CustomLoginWrapper">
            <div class="Skin-CustomLoginInnerWrapper">

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="Skin-CustomLoginFormTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>User Name</label></td>
                        <td><label>Password</label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Skin-CustomLoginInputs" id="LoginUserName"><span id="pageform_CZ1_2_CZ1_0_ctl01_ctl00" style="color:Red;display:none;">This field cannot be left empty.<br /></span><input name="pageform$CZ1$2$CZ1$0$ctl01$UserName" type="text" id="pageform_CZ1_2_CZ1_0_ctl01_UserName" size="35" class="Form-TextField" formID="3bd2a627-4646-4773-bb7a-262216b1e7aa" onkeypress="return(submitFormOnEnterFF('3bd2a627-4646-4773-bb7a-262216b1e7aa', event));" />
                        <td class="Skin-CustomLoginInputs" id="LoginUserPW"><span id="pageform_CZ1_2_CZ1_0_ctl02_ctl00" style="color:Red;display:none;">This field cannot be left empty.<br /></span><input name="pageform$CZ1$2$CZ1$0$ctl02$Password" type="password" id="pageform_CZ1_2_CZ1_0_ctl02_Password" size="35" class="Form-TextField" formID="3bd2a627-4646-4773-bb7a-262216b1e7aa" onkeypress="return(submitFormOnEnterFF('3bd2a627-4646-4773-bb7a-262216b1e7aa', event));" />
                        <td class="Skin-CustomLoginButton" id="LoginButton">
```

Comment: Have you considered using a tool such [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/)? With it you can record a navigation "session" and playback/edit.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain more? You want to be able to log-in to your site automatically even after the `Session` has expired?

Comment: No, I just want to be able to include it in a file to login to the site, click on a link, and logout. I can include the password so I don't have to go grabbing the session cookies or anything like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try [OpenId authorization](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-security-3-openid-login-with_13.html). If you logged in to Google you are welocme everywhere!

Comment: I've looked into it, but haven't been able to use either to help me yet. I thought it would be a basic script to login and then click the page, but it's' obviously a bit more difficult than I thought.

Comment: It's really easy to use if you have Spring Security integrated int your web apps

Comment: Do you think there is a way to just enter my info in the script above from the site?

Comment: If you want some more detailed example please see detailed tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLHyeSuBspI Here is updated info your such integration.